# Set up my own Dynamic DNS on a subdomain

Tags: subdomain, dynamic-dns, ddns

Im trying to set up a custom DDNS for my home network. I read an answer here that my hosting company server (bluehost) has all the tools needed to do this. digging into the DNS features it looks like they do but support said they don't. So I'm torn. 
Basically I know enough to get myself in trouble but not enough about DDNS to do this.

So i want SUBDOMAIN.example.com to point to my home IP for my VPN but when my IP updates/changes i want the dns direct on my host to change as well buy a custom DDNS

(I know I can do no-ip/dyndns/exc but they have been shifty)

Thank you.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: Ok thank you. Sorry I posted it here but someone posted here that they had done exactly what I'm trying to do on the same host. That's how I found my way here. Thanks for moving my question on over rather then just deleting it.